# Django Templates Syntax Error For If (Could not parse the remainder)

Tags: django, django-templates

Why does this not work in Django?

```
    {% for img in image_list %}
      {% if img != image_list[-1] %}
      <img src="{% get_media_prefix %}{{ img.image }}" class="img-fluid rounded" alt="Recipe Image Secondary">
      <br>
      {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
```

Simple Python (works):

```
for img in image_list:
    if img != (image_list[-1]):
        print(img)
```

`{% if img != image_list[-1] %}` 
throws a TemplateSyntaxError `Could not parse the remainder: '[-1]' from 'image_list[-1]'`

Comment: You can not use subscript (`[-1]`) in the Django template language.

Comment: so what's the "django" way to find the last element in this ``image_list``

Answer (score 1):

You can work with the [**`|last`** template filter <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#last) to obtain the last item of a sequence:

```
{% for img in image_list %}
  {% if img != image_list|last %}
  <img src="{{ img.image.url }}" class="img-fluid rounded" alt="Recipe Image Secondary">
  <br>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

or in this case work with [**`forloop.last`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#for):

```
{% for img in image_list %}
  {% if not forloop.last %}
  <img src="{{ img.image.url }}" class="img-fluid rounded" alt="Recipe Image Secondary">
  <br>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: thanks; look at my answer.. pretty elegant imo; but also maybe a css quirk as to why I need 2 ``<br>`` tags? just to get one black space..

Answer (score 0):

```
{% for img in image_list %}
{% if not forloop.last %}
  <img src="{% get_media_prefix %}{{ img.image }}" class="img-fluid rounded" alt="Recipe Image Secondary">
  <br><br>
{% else %}
  <img src="{% get_media_prefix %}{{ img.image }}" class="img-fluid rounded" alt="Recipe Image Secondary">
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```